# Django: Creating multiple instances for every form in a formset

Tags: django, loops, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have 2 models: `Post` and `Date`. A `Post` can have multiple `Date`s so I used formset for the latter. As expected, after submitting the form, my view has multiple Date contained in `request.POST`.

However, I still want to create multiple instances of `Date` for every form in the formset depending on the value of `male_total`. I tried using while loop to create multiple instances of Date (shown below) but it doesn't produce my desired results.

```
def create_post(request, method="POST"):
    DateFormSet = formset_factory(ExtraDateForm, extra=2, max_num=10, can_delete=True)
    if request.method == "GET":
        post_form = PostForm(request.GET or None)
        formset = DateFormSet(request.GET or None)
    elif request.method == "POST":
        post_form = PostForm(request.POST)
        formset = DateFormSet(request.POST)
        if post_form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            post = post_form.save()
            for form in formset:
                male_total = form.cleaned_data['male_number']
                x = 0
                while x < male_total:
                    date = form.save(commit=False)
                    date.post = post
                    date.sex_of_professional = "Male"
                    date.save()
                    x += 1
```

Is it due to the while loop or the way I instantiate?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your iteration. Whan you save a specific `ModelForm` of your `FormSet` you create a specific instance of the model. In other words: saving the same `ModelForm` multiple times does not give you multiple instances. So in your

```
while x < male_total:
    date = form.save(commit=False)
    ....
```

you are creating the same Date instance again and again. You need to use the `cleaned_data` from your form to explicitly create a new instance, e.g.

```
while x < male_total:
    date = Date(
        post = post,
        **form.cleaned_data
        )
    date.save()
```

(Instead of **form.cleaned_data you can of course als use and field from you cleaned_data explicity)

```
while x < male_total:
    date = Date(
              post = post,
              field1 = form.cleaned_data['field1']
           )
    date.save()
```